# How to remove headers and footer from the PPTX file using python?

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am not found any code related this.

not found packages also if anything is there let me know

Comment: no. i am asking to remove header and footer from the pptx file not editing

Comment: this has nothing at all to do with computer vision or NLP. I have removed those tags. please take the [tour] and review [ask]

Comment: python-pptx might well be the basis for this - as it provides a way to navigate and package back up a pptx file. However, on its own it won't do the job. I have my own reasons for wanting to build on python-pptx to manipulate headers and footers. But I can't get to it all that soon. Sorry. The approach to this is to dump the appropriate XML file in the .pptx (of which there are several) and then figure out how to manipulate that specific file.